# Choosing PostgreSQL Data Type for Money in Historical UK Pounds-Shillings-Pence System

Tags: database, postgresql, tags, currency

I am currently working on a project involving historical financial data in the UK, specifically using the pounds-shillings-pence system. I am uncertain about the best PostgreSQL data type to represent this type of currency. Despite searching on StackOverflow, I have not found a post containing all three terms "Pounds," "Shillings," and "Pence."

In my application, the input comprises character strings like `£57 19s 7d`, `£8 1s`, and `£30`. My goal is to perform summations of money values and multiplications of money values by dimensionless numbers. Ideally, I would prefer the result back in £sd notation, but I am also open to a floating-point representation.

My initial attempt using the `MONEY` data type resulted in an error:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (price MONEY);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('£30');
```

The error received was `invalid input syntax for type money: "£30"`. Is importing the data as a character string and then parsing it into a numeric type the most sensible option? If so, what is the best way to accomplish this? I am currently using PostgreSQL 16.1 on MacOS 14.2.1.

Any guidance or recommendations on handling historical currencies in PostgreSQL would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use numeric for the value and a char(3) for the currency code. The money data type depends on your configuration, don't use it. How you translate pounds to shillings and pence, that's up to your logic.

Comment: 1) You  got this `invalid input syntax for type money: "£30"` because of this [monetary  type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html): *Since the output of this data type is locale-sensitive, it might not work to load money data into a database that has a different setting of lc_monetary.* In other words your `lc_monetary` is not set to UK. 2) You will need to come up your own method of doing this either: a) Set up separate columns for £, s and d or b) Parse the strings `£57 19s 7d`, `£8 1s`, and `£30` and then do the math and output a new string.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for the hint about `lc_monetary`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, here is what I have tried:

```
SET lc_monetary = 'en_GB';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;
CREATE TABLE test_table (price MONEY);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('£30');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('£8 1s');
```

The first insertion works fine now. However, the second value, which has a non-zero shilling amount, throws the error: `invalid input syntax for type money: "£8 1s"`.

Should I conclude that there is no locale for early 20th-century GB money?

Comment: That is correct, I should have mentioned that in my previous comment. If you want to do this you will need to come up with your own process.